# List of pairs of lines from file [Java]

Tags: java

I am trying to create a simple method that would read the specified text file, line by line, and then it would print to the console every possible pair of those lines. I was trying to do that but it shows a strange result. My code looks like this:

```
public class MyList{
    List<String> elements = new LinkedList<>();

    public void createPairs() throws IOException {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("file.txt"));
        scanner.useDelimeter("\n");
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            elements.add(scanner.next());
        }
        scanner.close();

        for(String i: elements){
            for (String j:elements){
                System.out.println(i+" "+j);
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason it shows single lines looped lots of times and the for the last line it prints pairs properly. i.e. if the file.txt would contain:

```
1
2
3
```

The result would be:

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
... //it loops for some time
3 1
3 2
3 3
```

Reading the file to a list is probably fine because when I try to simply print the "elements" list it correctly shows each line of the file in separate List element.
I am not sure what am I doing wrong in here... Please help.

Comment: I can't reproduce when simply adding "1","2" and "3" to the list (ignoring the input file). Perhaps the file doesn't contain what you think it does.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code itself.

Comment: How many times did it loop in the output?

Comment: For test reasons I just created a new file that contains exatcly what I wrote above 1, 2 and 3 in separate lines. Now the result is exatcly as above, there are two loops o 1,2,3 and then pairs 3 1, 3 2, 3 3

Comment: You can also use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as a platform independent newline character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a Windows machine, aren't you?

On Windows, new line characters are represented by `\r\n` instead of `\n`. So when you press the Enter key when you create the file, you are actually creating `\r\n` characters.

This means that your text file looks like this to your code:

```
1\r\n2\r\n3
```

Now, you try to use a scanner to read it, with the delimiter being `\n`. What happens is that it reads the following characters:

```
1\r
2\r
3
```

Now, when you try to print the `\r` character, something quite different will happen. `\r` is a carriage return. This is one of those legacy characters from the typewriter era. On a typewriter, when you press the carriage return key, the "cursor" goes back to the start of the line, then you have to press the new line key to make it start a new line. So what happens if you only pressed the carriage return key? It will overwrite what is originally written at the start of the line! So the example below will only print "World".

```
System.out.println("Hello\rWorld");
```

That's why you get this funky output.

To solve this, stop using delimiters and try `nextLine` on the scanner, that will always read a whole line, no matter the OS.

Comment: Yup, I am using Windows. Now it works like a charm. Thanks :) I assume it's the famous Windows "backwards compatibility" in play here. Like with the length of the path variable limit :)